# Soma entre o valor de inputs falha em certos casos

Tags: javascript, html

Não consigo somar os valores e colocar a máscara corretamente entre os inputs.

Por exemplo, estou adicionando os seguintes valores em cada input:

- Input do *Valor da Adesão*: **`1.300,44`**
- Input 1 dos *Valores Dependentes*: **`1.300,44`**
- Input 2 dos *Valores Dependentes*: **`80,80`**

E no input do *Valor Total* vai ser colocada a soma do valor de todos os inputs juntos.

Com este código atual, se eu colocar **`80,79`** no Input 2 dos *Valores Dependentes*, o valor bate, mas **`80,80`** não bate. Não sei como resolver isso.

[image: Falha]

**Script do *Valor da Adesão*:**

```
function mascara(o, f) {
    v_obj = o
    v_fun = f
    setTimeout("execmascara()", 1)
}

function execmascara() {
    v_obj.value = v_fun(v_obj.value)
}

function mreais(v) {
    v = v.replace(/\D/g, "") //Remove tudo o que não é dígito
    v = v.replace(/(\d{2})$/, ",$1") //Coloca a virgula
    v = v.replace(/(\d+)(\d{3},\d{2})$/g, "$1.$2") //Coloca o primeiro ponto
    return v
}
```

**Input do *Valor da Adesão*:**

```
<input type="text" id="txt1" name="adesao" class="form-control calcular" placeholder="R$" onkeypress="mascara(this,mreais)" onkeyup="calcular()">
```

**Script do *Valor Total*:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function calcular() {
    var soma = $('.calcular').get().reduce(function(soma, el) {
        return (parseFloat(el.value.replace(/\./g, "").replace(",", "."), 10) || 0) + soma;
    }, 0);
    document.getElementById('result').value = soma;

    mascara(document.getElementById('result'), mreais);


}
</script>
```

**Input do *Valor Total*:**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="total" id="result" readonly>
```

**Script dos *Valores Dependentes*:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var AddTableRow = function(el) {
    var tbody = $(el).closest('table').find('tbody');
    var row = tbody.find('tr:last').clone();
    var name = row.find('.calcular').attr('name');
    var index = parseInt(name.match(/usuarios\[(\d+)\]\[valordependente\]/)[1], 10) + 1;
    row.find('[name^="usuarios["]').each(function() {
        if (this.name) {
            this.name = this.name.replace(/^usuarios\[\d+\]/, "usuarios[" + index + "]");
        }
    });
    tbody.append(row);
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso é um problema não apenas do JavaScript mas da computação em geral.

Você pode usar o método `.toFixed` na sua variável `soma` para normalizar isso.

```js
function calcular() {
    var soma = $('.calcular').get().reduce(function(soma, el) {
        return (parseFloat(el.value.replace(/\./g, "").replace(",", "."), 10) || 0) + soma;
    }, 0);

    soma = soma.toFixed(2);

    document.getElementById('result').value = soma;
    mascara(document.getElementById('result'), mreais);
}
```

Eu não testei, mas deve funcionar!

Comment: Aqui tem um link em inglês sobre `Floating-Number` para quem quiser saber mais a respeito. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Obrigado @Rafael